# What is the equivalent Matplotlib colormap for imagesc in Matlab?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib

As above. I'm reading help on imagesc

https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html

But still I cannot gather whether there's a name for this cmap. They say it is interpolation of RGB space. Anyway, what should I put in `plt.cmap` to that I get the same images in both cases?

Comment: Matlab's default colormap is [`parula`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parula.html). Not sure if Matplotlib has it; if not, you can take it from [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51986-perceptually-uniform-colormaps) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34859628/2586922)

Comment: Parula has been copyrighted by Matlab.  [Has someone made the Parula colormap in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34859628/has-someone-made-the-parula-colormap-in-matplotlib) has more information and workarounds. Note that parula has been created because of the many problems with the jet colormap.  To avoid the copyright issues, matplotlib created viridis as default colormap.